# How to set fullscreen pdf in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Here is my iframe :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="cv_frame">
    <?php if ($user_info["cv_path"] != "") { ?>
         <iframe width="100%" height="600" src="pathologists/<?=$PROFILE_ID?>/<?=$user_info["cv_path"]?>"></iframe>
    <?php } else { ?>
        Henüz paylaşılan bir cv bulunmamaktadır.                    
    <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- col-sm-12 -->
</div><!-- row -->
```

How it looks :

[image]

What i want :

[image]

I want to press stretch button at the first page load. How can i press this button automatically ?

Button :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The body has a default margin in most browsers. Try:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: this iframe is not fullscreen, it is a part of homepage.